# Correcting table name casing using Data Annotations in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, case-sensitive

I am trying to correct the casing of some tables in my model by using Data Annotations in Entity Framework 6.
Some tables in the database are wrongly cased as `SomeTable` but cannot be renamed.

The fix for this should be in the model like this:

```
[Table("SomeTable")]
public class Sometable
{
    …
}
```

However, this wrongly triggers a migration in the Entity Framework which includes both a `CreateTable("SomeTable")` and a `DropTable("SomeTable")` in the same `Up()` method, which obviously does not make sense.

Is there any way to force Entity Framework to understand that this table actually exists and it is just the casing that have changed?